# Define permit attributes with metaprogramming way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

We have `year1` to `year50` columns in "abc" modal.

Instead of defining them one by one like

```rb
params.require(:abc).permit(:year1, :year2, :year3, ... , :year50)
```

is there any other way to define those attributes?

Comment: This is a XY Problem. 

You shouldn't have 50 different columns and you shouldn't be passing 50 named parameters in the first place. Instead of you would use an assocation and use `fields_for` to create inputs that are parsed as an hash by Rack. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms

Comment: In any case metaprograming is not whats needed at all. If you really insist on keeping this fundamentially broken approach you could just generate an array (`ary = 1.upto(50).map {|i| "year#{i}".to_sym }`) and pass it with the splat operator `params.require(:abc).permit(*ary)`.

Comment: A) Why isn't this an array or JSON column? B) If these are in the schema, there should be methods for them automatically, and generating a list like that is trivial with `map`.